# how to tell if a timer is persistent via systemctl?

Tags: systemd, systemctl

The `systemctl status` seems do not output any difference when the persistent=true vs persistent=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`systemctl show` is your friend for checking all the properties of a unit:

```
$ systemctl show your.timer --property=Persistent
Persistent=yes
```